# No module named 'gdal' in jupyter-lab after installing GDAL on Mac

Tags: python, gdal

1. My mac version is Big Sur and python version is 3.9. I used brew to install gdal. When I run gdalinfo --version, I get the standard response:

`GDAL 3.2.0, released 2020/10/26`

2. But when I try import gdal in jupyter-lab, it always shows:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
In  [5]:
Line 1:     import gdal

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gdal'
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: Problem solved. The best way is the set up a virtual environment with python 3.9+ and then install 'gdal'.

Answer (score 2):

Have you try `from osgeo import gdal`?

This command works in my case, because the gdal package is installed as a sub-module of osgeo, rather than a stand-alone package.

Answer (score 0):

1. Find the location of _gdal.py. It should be in site packages, yourDirectoryPath/_gdal.py
2. Add that directory to your python path: `export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:yourDirectoryPath`
3. Try it out. If it works then add the line in step 2 to your .profile (.bashrc/.zshrc, etc)

(This was the installation note I kept for my older version of Python2 on the old Mac when it couldn't find the module)

One thing to note, the Python3 brew installed is different with Mac's built in python3, and lives in a different path, and gdal is supposed to link with this brew installed Python3, so, make sure your JupyterLab PYTHONPATH is pointed to the brew Python3.9 directory.

Comment: Thanks! But I didn't find any file named _gdal.py in /usr/ directory

Comment: Are you using Python3.9 that brew installed as your python interpreter? If not, then you'll need to set up JupyterLab PYTHONPATH to where the Python3.9 lives, for example in my case, it's /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/bin/python3.8. And since you're using python3.9, will need to find it accordingly. And then once you start to use brew installed Python, then it can accept gdal, then can avoid finding gdal.py...

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Anaconda:

```sh
conda install -c conda-forge gdal
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried to avoid conda since it made python management really messy for me. I will try if there is no way to fix this problem using pip or brew